# Let $A$ be a finite set and let $B$ be a subset of $A$ with $|A|=n$,$|B|=m$ and $0<m<n$. Count the subsets of $A$ containing $ B.$

Tags: combinatorics

Task is:

> Let $A$ be a finite set and let $B$ be a subset of $A$ with $|A|=n$,$|B|=m$ and $0< m < n$.Find a formula for the number of subsets of $A$ that contain $B$ and prove your statement.

I assume this is $2^m$ + something. $2^m$ would count the subsets containing only elements of $B$, but i'm not sure how the sets of the form $(a_1,a_2,b_1)$ or similar would be counted.

I'm having troubles with this so help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want subsets of $A$ that contain the whole $B,$ so any proper subset of $B$ will not be counted. Note that the question doesn't say "count subsets of $A$ that intersect $B$".

Comment: Ah, so could i count it by using a sum of n choose k, where k starts from m and goes to n? That would give me all subsets of cardinality larger than m.

Comment: No again.  Just because a set has cardinality at least $m$ does not mean it will contain $B$.  Your subsets all contain $B$ anyway.  What else might they contain and how many ways are there to choose this?

Comment: Understood! I would be counting sets of size >m for example which only contain B partly or contain even only elements from A!  I think by @Bernard 's answer i can count this by simply counting all sets of A\B, which would give me all the possible subsets i need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:

As such subsets can be complemented with subsets of $A$ that do not meet $B$ in a unique way, it is the same as counting the subsets of $A\smallsetminus B$. I suppose you can count them.

Comment: Clever! So could i count it by using a sum of n choose k, where k starts from 0 and goes to n-m? That would give me all subsets i need i believe?

Comment: You even don't have to do that, it is  a basic fact that if a set $X$ has $N$ elements, $\mathscr P(X)$ has $2^N$.

Comment: I understand! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad if I can help!